# strange characters(?) added to the end of my subject text

Tags: java, character-encoding, jms, jakarta-mail

I have a problem with my java code sending email to users. There is some problem with the encoding of the email. When the email arrives to email account the subject line ($subject) has encoding problems as has strange characters(?) added to the end of my subject text.

The email message content itself is fine just the subject line(?) I have searched all over but cant find,after using Unicode and content type as text/html mail body have no problem with special character
(`ó`) but same fix is not working for subject line.

I have a class that sends an email with javamail, with a text like
this one in subject :

> "Estimado Iván Escobedo:

The problem is that when the mail arrives to its destination, it
arrives this way:

> "Estimado Iv?n Escobedo:

All the `á`, `é`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, etc special characters are replaced with `?`.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You told that strange characters are been added to end of subject line, but your concrete problem seems to be just that "special characters" are been replaced by question marks. What exactly is now the problem you're having? Your question title and problem description are not consistent with the described symptoms.

Comment: thanks for reply,sorry for bad explanation,if these char á, é, í, ó, ú are subject of mail ,it is replacing with ? mark .same thing was happening with message in mail but after changing content type with "Text/html" and using unicode it is working but same thing is not happing with subject ,it is just showing unicode vale if I am taking unicode for subject also.

Comment: RFC5322 headers are 7-bit ASCII only; if you want to use 8-bit characters, you have to encode them in accordance with RFC2048.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like that to read the message properly:

```
TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage)message;
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(txtMessage.getText().getBytes ("ISO-8859-15"))
```

***Edit :***

Sanjay found the solution.

In order to set properly the message before sending, use :

```
MimeUtility.encodeText(SubjectText, "ISO-8859-15", "Q")
```

> [encodeText](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) :
>
> Encode a RFC 822 "text" token into mail-safe form as per RFC 2047.
>
> The given Unicode string is examined for non US-ASCII characters. If the string contains only US-ASCII characters, it is returned as-is. If the string contains non US-ASCII characters, it is first character-encoded using the specified charset, then transfer-encoded using either the B or Q encoding. The resulting bytes are then returned as a Unicode string containing only ASCII characters.

Note that this method should be used to encode only "unstructured" RFC 822 headers.

Comment: thanks for reply,the main problem with subject for mail,if these char á, é, í, ó, ú are subject of mail ,it is replacing with ? mark .same thing was happening with message in mail but after changing content type with "Text/html" and using unicode it is working but same thing is not happing with subject ,it is just showing unicode vale if I am taking unicode for subject also.

Comment: Do you set the subject like this : `message.setString("Subject", subject);`? If yes does the subject at this time is properly encoded?

Comment: I got Fix for this issue.extra char can be added in subject by using below code when we are setting subject :mailNotificationHelper.setSubject((MimeUtility.encodeText(SubjectText, "ISO-8859-15", "Q")));

Comment: Nice good  job! If someone need documentation here for more explanation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html. I add the edit it's better if someone need this info than reading into comments ;)