# Email attached Chinese content is showing questions marks in the email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Email subject is converting into Chinese but email contents attached in the file is not converting into Chinese or Japanese , its displaying ???????. Could somebody help me ?
Below is my code :

```
  MimeMessage localMsg = null;
  Properties localProp = null;
  MimeBodyPart localMimeBodyPart = null;
  Multipart localMultipart = null;
  MimeMessage localMsg = null;
  DataSource localDs = null;

   Session localSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(localProp, null);
   localMsg = new MimeMessage(localSession);

  localMsg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
  localMsg.setSubject(subjectArg, "UTF-8"); 


            localMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            localMimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyMsgArg, "text/html;charset=utf-8");

            localMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
            localMultipart.addBodyPart(localMimeBodyPart);

            for (int localInt1 = 0; localInt1 < attachmentsArg.length; localInt1++)
            {
                if ((attachmentsArg[localInt1] != null))
                {
                    localMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                    localDs = attachmentsArg[localInt1];

                    localMimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler( localDs));
                    localMimeBodyPart.setFileName(localDs.getName());
                    localMultipart.addBodyPart(localMimeBodyPart);

                }
            }

            localMsg.setContent(localMultipart);


        localMsg.setSentDate(new Date());

        localMsg.saveChanges();

        Transport.send(localMsg);
```

Comment: please show us the code for setting the subject and email contents so we can see what the issue is. it's probably something due to not setting the encoding correctly or a wrong conversion.

Comment: Check encodings everywhere. Chinese sometimes has encoding Java cannot handle by default (gb2312).

Comment: Did you properly encode `bodyMsgArg`?

Comment: I think this post is related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9378084/1140748. Can you try something like `localMsg.setContent((MimeUtility.encodeText(localMultipart, "utf-8", "Q")))`